# TypeError: 'Tega' object not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, serialization

Here is my code in `views.py`

```
user_driver_list = []
tega_list = []
for driversprofiles in check_all_columns:

    fetched_profile = fetch_rafiki_profile()[0]
    driver_rafiki_session_existance = RafikiDriverSession.objects.filter(rafiki_number=fetch_rafiki_profile()[0], drivers_profile=driversprofiles)

    user_driver = User.objects.filter(username=driversprofiles.user)
    user_driver_list.append(UserSerializer(user_driver, many=True).data)
    print("A")
    latest_tegas = Tega.objects.filter(driver_profile=driversprofiles).latest(field_name='start_time')
    tega_list.append(TegaSerializer(latest_tegas, many=True).data)
    print("B")
```

I am trying got filter and get all latest Tegas for every matching driver in the `check_all_columns` QuerySet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `TegaSerializer(latest_tegas, many=True)`, but `latest_tegas` in your case is just a single object.

The problem is following line:

```
latest_tegas = Tega.objects.filter(driver_profile=driversprofiles).latest(field_name='start_time')
```

`many=True` indicates that you pass multiple objects into the serializer.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#latest) for `latest()`:

> Returns the latest object in the table based on the given field(s).